# Which SQL server version supports varchar(MAX) data type

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, varchar

We should use varchar(max) when length of string varies and max limit is 2GB.
Is it supported in older versions like SQL server 2005?

If supports then still the MAX size limit is 2GB?

Comment: Are you going to use SQL Server 2005? Sure you're not.

Comment: All supported versions support the `MAX` data types.

Comment: Yes, the `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)` datatypes were introduced in SQL Server **2005** - but you should **really NOT** use such an unsupported version of SQL Server anymore - especially not for new work! We're on SQL Server **2019** by now ....

Comment: @Ilyes our system is very old and still some clients using SQL Server 2005. 
For the fix we are targeting all clients.

Comment: Personally, my stance would be that if a client isn't using a version of SQL Server that isn't supported by Microsoft (and hasn't been for some years) then they can't expect to be supported by a 3rd party either. There are **significant** differences between 2005 and 2019.

Comment: Yes, It is supported.

Comment: I fully Agree with you @Larnu but I am a developer and decision makers are on top level and I report the same multiple times.